# Convert jsp object to json

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I am working with jsp and I need to convert it into json:

In javascript:

```
listas = "<%=ics.GetVar("ListasConsumo")%>";
```

The result `console.log(listas);` is the next string:

```
LtEmConsumptionPerHourResponseDTO [
    billedConsumptionActive=ConsumptionDTO [
        consumptionHour00=99.17600000000000, 
        consumptionHour01=105.77600000000000, 
        consumptionHour02=115.45600000000000, 
        consumptionHour03=121.30800000000000
    ], 
    billedConsumptionReactive=ConsumptionDTO [
        consumptionHour00=0.00000000000000, 
        consumptionHour01=0.00000000000000, 
        consumptionHour02=0.00000000000000, 
        consumptionHour03=0.00000000000000
    ],
    registersTotal=24
]
```

Which is the best way to do the convertion to json?

Comment: Take a look here: http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.it/2013/02/custom-jsp-taglib-to-convert-object-to.html

Comment: the best way to json is JSTL.